# Unable to locate the .NET core SDK

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have a .NET core solution project targeting .Net core 2.1.

In my new machine, VS 2019 has been installed(.Net core 3.1.101 is installed with VS 2019)

Now when I try to run the project it says version 2.1 was not found.

So I installed/uninstalled different .Net core 2.1 SDKs.

Finally, I have below SDKs installed in my machine.

1. 2.1.809
2. 3.1.101

Now while opening the solution, none of the project loads and I see the below error in the output window:

> 'Unable to locate the .Net core SDK, check that it is installed and
> version specified in global.json matched with the installed version.'

I don't have global.json in my project. Though I created the dummy one and provided SDK version 3.1.101 in that; however, it didn't work.

How can I know which version my project is trying to get and throwing this error?

Comment: Please try opening the project file in notepad and check the versions

Comment: .csproj doesn't have any specific SDK version mentioned. You mean which version?

Host project .csproj file has TargetFramework netcoreapp2.1 and remaining projects are netstandard 2.0

Comment: Please try to reload those projects

Comment: Already tried reloading but that doesn't work.

Also removed all the SDK and keep 3.1.101 but that also didn't work.

Even  when I create simple new .Net Core console project, the solution doesn't load.

Comment: Can you check if it's showing proper .net core version from command prompt `dotnet --version`

Comment: C:\Program Files\dotnet>dotnet --version

it shows 3.1.101

Comment: try from command prompt if you can build. `dotnet build` or `dotnet run`

Comment: I uninstalled VS 2019 and re-install VS 2019. Now the version of VS 2019 is 19.7 and that of .NET SDK is 3.1.7.

After this, I am able to open the solution and load the projects.

Now I just want to know, If I want to run the project which is targeting .Net core 2.1 then which SDK should I install?

Currently only SDK that is installed is 3.1.7

Comment: You can install .net sdk 2.1. All the sdks can be install and run side by side.

Answer (score 3):

For my case, it works while checking dotnet --version, dotnet --list-sdks etc. Environment variables also set correctly. Everything looks fine but when I tried to Load the Xamarin Forms project, it keep throwing this error.

Even if I create new Xamarin Forms project, the Android and iOS are there, but the Forms failed to load.

After trying here and there, my solution was to delete the folder at C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet, because I have already got the working Core at C:\Program Files\dotnet. I think Visual Studio looked for the library at x86 first, before trying in x64.

Now it works.

Comment: Thanks, I recently upgraded the VS2022 preview and started facing issues with VS2019. I renamed C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet folder

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else encountering this issue, maybe this could help. 
This instructions is for Rider but I believe its the same also for VisualStudio.

Go to **Help -> Find Action -> type:"Manage .Net SDK".**

This should open the "*Manage .Net/.Net Core SDK for Solution*" window.
Then, 
you can select from the list of installed versions, which one you want.

OR - what I did, 
I select in Roll-forward policy input, latest minor, which trying to find the installed version with the most updated number in minor.

**For Example:** 
The solution expected .Net 6.x, but with latestMajor it found the .Net 7.x installed and try to use it for this solution. 
With latestMinor, it selected the latest 6.x installed on my PC, and success to works with it.

[image: Manage_sdk_for_solution]

Answer (score 0):

Re-installation of VS 2019 solved the issue of loading projects.

After re-installation VS 2019 is upgraded to 16.7.2 and .NET Core SDK to 3.1.401.

Now to successfully run the project targeting .NET core 2.1, I installed .NET Core SDK 2.1.810.

[dotnet.microsoft.com/download-visual-studios-sdks](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download-visual-studios-sdks) - This can help which version to install.

Answer (score 0):

### **Step 1**

Install *Visual Studio Installer*

> VS Installer should be related to your VS version i.e. 2019/2020/2022

### **Step 2**

If you have installed multiple Visual Studio Versions, all will appear.
Look for the one you are using or the one which is not opening the project.

> for example I have only Visual Studio  2019 installed so it will only show me VS 2019 else there will be 2021 2022 versions available.

### **Step 3**

There you will see the options to **Modify / Uninstall / Update.**
Update from there, you don't have to delete your project or update anything else.
From here, it will update all the necessary items and removes the one not needed.

> Removing the items by the VS installer doesnot effects anything. It just replace the new updates available.

Once it is done updating, Project will load successfully and it automatically update   *.Net core SDK* and adds the updated version to *global.json*